# How to right declare a composite java JSON object from string?

Tags: java, android, json, string, httprequest

i have this string which i'm using for testing of api:

```
{"limit":30, "offset":"0", "filters": [{"property":"vlc.vlc","operator":"=","value":"DEKU113829"}]}
```

I would like to create JSOn object for processing in Android app using the:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();         
json.put("limit", 30);
json.put("offset", "0");
```

But i don't know how to create "filters" section using put method...

What is the right and most effective solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

JSONObject/JSONArray supports a "builder-esque" pattern and [`put`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) can be chained - it will return the same (but modified) object.

```
JSONObject json =
   new JSONObject()
   .put("limit", 30)
   .put("offset", "0") /* but should be 0? */
   .put("filters",
        new JSONArray()
        .put(new JSONObject()
             .put("property", "vlc.vlc")
             .put("operator", "=")
             .put("value", "DEKU113829")
        )
   );
```

Alternatively, look into a POJO mapper like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), which I would recommend overall for ease of use and consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();         
json.put("limit", 30);
json.put("offset", "0");

JSONArray js_array = new JSONArray();  

JSONObject json_obj = new JSONObject();         
json_obj.put("property", "vlc.vlc");
json_obj.put("operator", "=");
json_obj.put("value", "DEKU113829");

js_array.put(json_obj);

json.put("filters",js_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Gson Library. Your model objects for the JSON will be

```
public class MainModel
    {
        private int limit ;
        public int getlimit()
        {
                return this.limit;
        }
        public void setlimit(int limit)
        {
                this.limit = limit;
        }
        private String offset ;
        public String getoffset()
        {
                return this.offset;
        }
        public void setoffset(String offset)
        {
                this.offset = offset;
        }
        private ArrayList<Filter> filters ;
        public ArrayList<Filter> getfilters()
        {
                return this.filters;
        }
        public void setfilters(ArrayList<Filter> filters)
        {
                this.filters = filters;
        }
    }

public class Filter
    {
        private String property ;
        public String getproperty()
        {
                return this.property;
        }
        public void setproperty(String property)
        {
                this.property = property;
        }
        private String operator ;
        public String getoperator()
        {
                return this.operator;
        }
        public void setoperator(String operator)
        {
                this.operator = operator;
        }
        private String value ;
        public String getvalue()
        {
                return this.value;
        }
        public void setvalue(String value)
        {
                this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

You can populate your filter object and create MainModel object and add the filter object to it. Next use Gson library as below to get your json string

```
Gson gsonParser = new Gson();
String jsonString = gsonParser.toJson(mainModelObject);
```